# Pass generated Sass variables back to Gulp stream

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

On my project, I need to generate a second Sass file with theme-specific code, which will be generated when Sass (inside a Gulp task) is processed.

```scss
@mixin theme-set($key, $value) {
  @if not global_variable_exists(theme-config) {
    $theme-config: () !global;
  }

  // magic stuff here, which will be appended to $theme-config
}

.class1 {
  @include theme-set(foo, bar);
}

.class2 {
  @include theme-set(bar, baz);
}
```

The mixin `theme-set` will generate Sass map key-value pairs that will be appended to `$theme-config`.

Now, my issue is that I need to pass `$theme-config` back to the Gulp stream so I can generate a separate `theme.sass` (or `theme.css`) file as override stylesheet of the `main.css`

Then, the `$theme-config` should be imported in another file (ideally in the same stream, or passing it to another stream in the same task, using merge-stream) that would then generate `theme.css`.

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: 1) Do you need two separate build steps? In other words, can what you want accomplished be done with a single step? 2) Are there environment/build variables you can extract which is common to each step?

Comment: @Auroratide a single task is not required, but would be better (maybe using merge-streams, to avoid building separate tasks and additional intermediary files). I'm not understanding your suggestion about environment variables. I also updated the question with info about what I want to do with `$theme-config`.